# Use prebuilt JNI library in Android Studio 3.1

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I was given a shared object (*.so file) that I need to reference from my app. I know for a fact that the shared object uses JNI. Now, I have some experience with Android app development, but none with native code. I have looked at a lot of answers here on StackOverflow and on Google in general, but none seem to fit in my question.

Basically, this shared object was for another app, and I have the code for that app, and now I need to implement it in my app. I am lost as to where I should start or what I should do. If anyone can help guide me through this process that would be very nice.

Also, I do not have the source files nor the header files for the shared object. I do know the name of the native method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have the Java sources that defined these native methods originally, you can often reverse engineer the necessary native method definitions from the **.so** file itself. E.g., if the library exports `Java_com_example_testjni_MainActivity_stringFromJni`, then you must add a Java class

```
package com.example.thestjni;

class MainActivity {
    public native static String stringFromJni();
}
```

This does not give your the correct parameters or return types for the **native** methods. Also, you must guess whether the **native** method should be declared **static** or not.

To be on the safe side, you will add a static constructor to this class, to make sure the library is loaded:

```
package com.example.thestjni;

class MainActivity {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("thirdparty");
    }
    public native static String stringFromJni();
}
```

You are free to rename the 3<sup>rd</sup> party library to your liking, but not the package and not the class. You don't care if the original Java class declared the native method **private**, you can safely declare it **public** in your project.

To find the names of JNI functions exported by prebuilt library **libthirdparty.so**, you can use the **nm** tool provided with Android NDK toolchains:

```
nm -D libthirdparty.so | grep Java_
```

Comment: nm says the file is truncated. And when I run the app I get this error:
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x4 in tid 29909 (yapp). I feel like I am in way over my head here, though it seemed so simple at first. Any suggestions?

Comment: How exactly did you obtain this lib? As for sigfault, this could easily happen if your guess about parameters or return type of some native method was wrong.

Comment: I made a mistake when copying over the class with native function and accidentally put the wrong parameters. So you're right. I fixed it and everything works as planned. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Java code for another app that uses it- find the Java code in the other library that calls it.  Those functions should be defined with the keyword native.  Take that class(es), without renaming or changing the package, and put it in your project.  Now you can call those native functions via the Java native function definitions.

Of course without source you can't compile for any other architecture.  So hopefully you have the .so files for all the appropriate ones.  Remember to load the library if those class(es) don't do it for you.

Comment: Thanks, I got it to load the library.